# Memory-Mapped Files & Transparent Persistence of Java Objects

Tags: java, memory-mapped-files, object-persistence

Greeting All,

I want to achieve transparent persistence of Java objects through memory-mapped files (utilize the OS paging/swapping mechanism).

**My problem is: how can I move a Java object to my memory-mapped block ?
Plus, how can I force a new object instance to reside in such blocks ?**

As you all know, a memory-mapped block can be seen as a byte array, and what I am really asking here is how to overlap the address space of Java objects with the one of such arrays ? So that we can still manipulate the data via objects while OS handles persistence transparently (writes dirty pages).

If Java does not allow me for this, what cross-platform & garbage-collecting OO language would you advise me to use ?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Please, what is your memory mapped file from a java point of view ? Is it a File, or a MappedByteBuffer or other ? Thanks.

Comment: So far I am using a MappedByteBuffer but I am willing to use something else if it is going to help me achieve transparent persistent via paging/swapping while still being able to use my objects as objects and not just raw data in a byte array

Comment: Actually I discovered that in Java the issue is complicated by the Garbage Collector doing in-memory defragmentation when finalizing objects.

Comment: I also looked at C#. Although it allows for "unsafe" code with pointers, it does NOT allow pointers of referential types (objects).

Comment: Am I asking something stupid or hard ?!

Comment: It depends on what you're looking to achieve. If all you care about is persistence of primitive data, then it's easy: your real objects wrap a `ByteBuffer` that refers to some location within your file, and delegate all getters and setters to that buffer. As you move up the scale of complexity to add strings and object graphs, you'll find that you're implementing your own memory manager. Rather a lot of work for little return, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way you can do this is by using your own Java VM and adding this functionality. Of course the code that you would write would not be in Java but in the language the VM is implemented in. Quite some time ago Gemstone used this approach for their object database engine.

Todays object databases (I work on one.) don't do things this way. It's much more straightforward to enhance bytecode to track field access and to use reflection or injected methods to turn objects into some kind of serialized form. This performs quite good. If you want to support querying, you have to work with individual field values anyway to index them.

For us it would just not be doable to maintain a VM for all the platforms that we want to run on. We also couldn't possibly convince serious customers to rely their entire (banking) application on a VM that we customize.

If you are seriously interested in producing a solution based on a Java VM:
There used to be an interesting Java research project for orthogonal transparent persistence called "Forest". You may be able to find old papers or even source code.

If you are looking for a different language to take "objects" from memory directly: C++ will let you do that. There are some old object databases written in C++ that use this approach.
...but hey, that's crazy stuff, using page faults to load objects. These kind of object databases produced the bad image. I hope we will turn it around again soon.

Answer (score 3):

This is afaik not possible. And there are several good reasons why the runtime doesn't allow this.

- The memory layout of your object is part of the JVM internals. Each JVM can make it own decisions how to layout objects. This layout can change over releases. When you memory-map a object to a file, you would run into trouble. What happens when the object-layout has changed? Crash, update the file, do magic? In the end memory-mapping objects to files would require to specify a fixed object-layout.
- What happens if you add/remove a field? Then the object-layout has changed for sure. You cannot memory-map a file with the old memory-layout.
- A object has also additional information, like the VTable for virtual function-calls, fields for lock-states etc. Do you want the map them also? Probably not, because thats internal runtime-state. So you would require to alway ignore a few bytes or split-up objects. That would make the memory-layout extremely complex.
- The garbage collector compacts the memory to minimize fragmentation by moving objects around. Therefore there needs to be a 'fixation'-mechanism for objects. (that's possible in .NET, for interop-reasons)
- The garbage collector works in generations. A object if first allocated on a young generation. As it survives it is moved to other generation. A memory-mapped object would require an exception.

For all these reasons you cannot memory-map Java/.NET-objects. Supporting such a feature would make the JVM/CLR extremely complex.

The JVM/CLR still give you access to Memory-Mapped files as an array-like abstraction, where you can write/read bytes. On top of this you can implement your persistence-mechanism. From simple serialisation to complex databases. 
There are object-databases which come quite close to provide transparent persistence. Then objects behave like persistent datastructures / memory-mapped objects.

Comment: What do you mean with 'overriden'. Of course it's possible to write an different GC and integrate it in the JVM/CLR. And both bring different GC with it. But it certainly not easy to write a efficient garbage collector. Furthermore a efficient GC works together with the other parts of the runtime. For example with the JIT-compilier (adding write-barriers).

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Java, by design, enforces type safety and referential integrity. That is, if I have a field of reference type T, I know it points to a instance of T. (Barring heap-pollution introduced by type erasure). This is in contrast to "unsafe" languages such a C++ where it is quite possible for a reference to point to an invalid location, where that reference can cause "memory corruption".

If Java allowed to treat a byte[] as `Object`, it could not guarantee such referential integrity.

Comment: Why we cannot have like MemoryMap<T> of some Class type instead of fixing it for bytes ?

Comment: Because the file you map to memory is not necessarily consistent, Java would have to verify that when loading it. Also, what about references to data outside the memory mapped region? Every Java object keeps a reference to its class object, which in turn knows its classloader, which in turn knows where classes are located on the file system ...